# How to trust all ssl certificates on Worklight 6.2

Tags: android, cordova, ssl, https, ibm-mobilefirst

My issue is how to connect between client and worklight server via https.

I've use self-signed ssl (without CA)  and i want somehow to trust all certificates by pass the SSLHandshakeError.

Environments:

- Worklight 6.2
- Android platform

It is possible to use "single-tone" `HttpClientManager.getInstance().getHttpClient()` like this and some how add some custom sslFactory or something like this...

PS.
I've done everything written in the guide [wl 6.2 ssl](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_configuring_SSL_WL_adapters_backend_servers_certificates.html?lang=en)
I've tried with **customCordovaWebViewClient** and to override sslErrorHandler but this doesn't work for me

I know that there is a variant to create self-certificates with CA bit and install it manually on devices but that is not possible for me...

Comment: What the document you have attached isn't Client and Worklight server  SSL ? The name itself says its adapter and server SSL.

Comment: Follow this for what you require Client and server with Configuring SSL by using untrusted certificates http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/c_ssl_config.html?lang=en

Comment: I've attached the wrong link

Comment: What exactly is your scenario? What do you want to achieve? Is it just testing that an SSL connection work? Do you just want to ignore SSL certificates on your app in production? If it is just testing, are you testing on emulators and/or real devices?

Comment: @Daniel A. González I want to trust SSL certificates in production, because the production is in private network without world-wide access, For that case i'm trying to add sslFactory with mine keystore... using **HttpClientManager.setSSLSocketFactory**

Comment: That is currently not supported as far as I know. You might need to open a feature request.

Comment: I would also suggest considering just using HTTP, as using HTTPS like this is not really safer than regular HTTP. The only benefit is that the traffic gets encrypted, but anyone who wants to spoof the server can easily do so, rendering such encryption useless, and worse because it gives the illusion of security. But I assume you already knew this.

Comment: @DanielA.González, Sounds like you can also include the above as an answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

That is currently not supported as far as I know. You might need to open a feature request.

I would also suggest considering just using HTTP, as using HTTPS like this is not really safer than regular HTTP. The only benefit is that the traffic gets encrypted, but anyone who wants to spoof the server can easily do so, rendering such encryption useless, and worse because it gives the illusion of security. But I assume you already knew this.